# Why is Selenium's explicit wait not working in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The following code is using Selenium library. The problem is the trace command never gets printed given that it should be printed n times until the element becomes visible.

```cs
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(new SystemClock(), driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("test.com");
//  Thread.Sleep(1000);
wait.Until(_ =>
{
    Trace.WriteLine("aa");
    return ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//button[@data-a-target='change-country-button']"));
});
```

When I activate the commented line it works (most of the time).

Comment: How are you executing the application or test? This can make a difference, since the trace output might be directed to a different place depending on how you execute the program.

Comment: Debug; put a breakpoint on the Trace line. See if execution is paused. Then you can look where Trace is routing its output.

Comment: The trace is outputting to the console, I tried it and it's working . Breakpoints doesn't work neither on the trace line or the output line.

Comment: What are you trying to test exactly? If you're trying to see if the wait occurs, you would be better off just putting the log after the wait. If you really need that to happen, you might look into using the `PollingInterval` setting when instantiating your WebDriverWait.

Comment: Also as a heads up, but `ExpectedConditions` is the old way to do waits, and has been marked for deprecation, see this for the updated way https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

Comment: the internal code block should be called at a constant interval untill the expected conditions return true. the problem is that the internal code block never gets called

Comment: the code beneath these lines never gets reached untill a timeout exception happens

Comment: I tried the other method written in the documentation `Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")))` still not working

Comment: Is the element within an iframe? If so you will need to switch to that context before the element can be waited upon.

Answer (score 0):

The *`wait`* object is ideally used inconjunction with *`ExpectedConditions`* only and *`ExpectedConditions`* doesn't work in loops.

Hence, the 2 lines within *`Until`* doesn't get executed in any loop neither ***aa*** gets printed in loop as you are expecting.

---

### Update

Ideally the line of code incorporating [***WebDriverWait***](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) should have been:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(new SystemClock(), driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IWebElement myElement = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@data-a-target='change-country-button']")));
```

In a single line:

```
IWebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(new SystemClock(), driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@data-a-target='change-country-button']")));
```

Comment: Could you pls provide an example of the correct code

Comment: I tried that before and didn't work sadly

Comment: also I don't have any loops in my code but the documentaion says that explicit wait will call the function at equal intervals untill the element shows up